# Последовательная запись данных в jpeg файлы

Tags: java, файлы, изображения, active-directory, jpeg

Коротко о сути моего вопроса: пользователь выбирает директорию с jpeg файлами. У меня есть данные, которые нужно в эти файлы записать. В каждый файл различные данные. Таким образом мне нужно заполнить всю директорию. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Не очень понятно. Вам надо вывести все изображения папки, с публикацией их данных. Типа - картинка, имя, размер, дата и т. д.. То для этого есть список(RecyclerView).

Comment: Нужно добавить к изображению еще что-то? Приписку, ушки на фотку нацепить и прочее?

Comment: Записать в jpeg-файлы - имеется в виду стеганография или сделать вотермарки?

Comment: Дубликат: [Запись ключевых слов в jpeg-файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870627/Запись-ключевых-слов-в-jpeg-файл)